# MongoDB create user kills restart

Tags: mongodb

We use Ansible for installing MongoDB, but we have a problem with installing MongoDB (2.2 - an old version, but currently standard in our platform) on CentOS 6.x 64bit.

This playbook will download the `mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.2.0.tgz` file and extract it into `/opt`. We add `/etc/mongodb.conf` and install the init script. This is all fine and you can (re)start the mongo service on provisioned machines.

But when we create an user in the 'admin' database:

```
echo 'db.addUser("mongoadmin", "password");' | mongo admin
```

it will succeed, but when we restart MongoDB, it will fail and keep failing. I "played" with the `auth = true` option, but it keeps failing. Not only for the 'admin' database, but also for the 'local' or other newly created databases.

It all worked until a few weeks ago and I don't know why. We have it on multiple machines, so it isn't related to a single machine.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Is this only happening with Ansible or as well if you manually create that user and restart?

Comment: Also when manually creating the user in mongo and restart the service. Manually as in the echo statement, but also placing it in an js file and running it as: mongo admin < /tmp/admin_user.js

Comment: OK. I removed the Ansible tag is it is unrelated then.